# Pull first image from rich text field

Tags: entries, richtext

Is there a way to output the first image of a rich text field?

At the moment the template code is as simple as:

```
{{ entry.body }}
```

The purpose is so that I can use the image in the meta section of the template. If there is no easy solution I could change it to be a Matrix field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to do this, is by creating a small Twig extension plugin that uses PHP's html parser to find the first occurrence of an IMG tag and return the src of that tag to your template. [This](https://cameronspear.com/blog/craft-cms-twig-filter-extension/) is a step-by-step explanation of how to create your very own Twig filter.

You could then to this:

{{ entry.body | firstImageSrc }}

And it would return the url you need.

**The easiest way, however, is to add an asset field to your Entry Type's field layout and choose a file manually.**

Comment: Just discovered you can do this with the hacksaw plugin: {{ article.articleText|hacksaw(hack='image')|striptags('<img>')|raw }}